# Webpack - merge an existing webpack bundle with new javascript files

Tags: webpack

I'm currently trying to include an existing webpack bundle in my solution and to output everything as one big webpack bundle.

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR in chunk lib [entry]
bundle.js
Conflict: Multiple assets emit to the same filename bundle.js
```

**Webback config**:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

let inputFolderPath = "js\\";
let outputFolderPath = "dist\\";
let bundleName = "bundle.js";

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }],
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery"
      })
  ],
  externals: {
    myScoreUILib: 'MyScoreUILib'
  }, 
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, inputFolderPath),
  entry: {
    app: './app.js',
    lib: './lib.bundle'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, outputFolderPath),
    filename: bundleName,
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Online repo: https://github.com/umarmw/js-extend-module-wp

Is it possible to merge a webpack bundle inside another? or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the above issue by using a combination of **node.js** **readFileSync** and **writeFileSync** along with [webpack-shell-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin)

**Webpack config**:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackShellPlugin = require('webpack-shell-plugin');

let inputFolderPath = "js\\";
let outputFolderPath = "dist\\tmp\\";
let bundleName = "bundle.js";

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }],
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: "jquery",
          jQuery: "jquery"
      }),

      new WebpackShellPlugin({
        onBuildStart:[], 
        onBuildEnd:['node node.bundle']
      }),

  ],
  externals: {
    myScoreUILib: 'MyScoreUILib'
  }, 
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, inputFolderPath),
  entry: {
    app: './app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, outputFolderPath),
    filename: "app.js"
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

and '**node.bundle.js**'

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const lib = path.join(__dirname, './dist/tmp/lib.bundle.js');
const app = path.join(__dirname, './dist/tmp/app.js');
const bundle = path.join(__dirname, './dist/bundle.js');

let libContent =  fs.readFileSync(lib); 
let appContent =  fs.readFileSync(app); 

fs.writeFileSync(bundle, libContent+'\n'+appContent);
```

In the end, I've end up just concatenating the two webpack bundle together using node.js